# Uncheck a checkbox after if statement

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am creating an admin tool for our helpdesk and I want the option to allow the tool to stay on top of other windows via a checkbox. This is the inital setup of the checkbox:

```
$cbx_OnTop                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$cbx_OnTop.text            = "Keep On Top"
$cbx_OnTop.AutoSize        = $false
$cbx_OnTop.width           = 175
$cbx_OnTop.height          = 20
$cbx_OnTop.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(24,290)
$cbx_OnTop.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,8'
$cbx_OnTop.Checked         = $false
```

I then have the following function:

```
function KeepOnTop {

    if ($cbx_OnTop.Checked = $True) {

            $AdminTool.TopMost = $True

    } else {

            $AdminTool.TopMost = $false

    }

}
```

How do I add the function to this checkbox?

Comment: CheckedChanged event of the CheckBox maybe ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Add_CheckStateChanged** event is the command you are looking for.

```
$cbx_OnTop.Add_CheckStateChanged({
    If ($cbx_OnTop.Checked) {
        $AdminTool.TopMost = $True
    } Else {
        $AdminTool.TopMost = $false
    }
)}
```

Comment: Thanks @ArcSet, I decided to change the design and user a button instead, but I believe your answer was what I was initially looking for.